# How would I have Spring authenticate against the database I am using?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have the following SecurityConfiguration in my Spring-boot powered API.

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/helloWorld").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER")
            .and().withUser("tester").password("password").roles("NOROLE");
    }
}
```

Now, that is fine - it gets me up and running, and testing my resources, etc.

But at the minute, I really don't know how to adapt this to work with users I store in the DB. I understand the logic I need to follow :

1. Take credentials (such as email and pass)
2. findOne on email
3. If no record found, the user is invalid - decline auth, do not return token.
4. Else, encrypt the provided password, and check if it matches the stored password.
5. if It matches, create the token, and give it back to the client.
6. else, decline auth - do not return a token.

I have done this before with node.js, mongo, and mongoose - but am unfamiliar with adapting this approach in Spring. I could really use some guidance. I have been googling this a fair amount, but all of the auth tutorials seem to just dump in this approach that I have, and then trust that you know how to adapt it later - which sucks for those of us who are not using the tutorials as a reference, but rather to actually LEARN spring.

All help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of asking the question how about reading [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#jc-authentication-jdbc) which explains how to use a database? Basically Spring Security does all you want...

Comment: And this is pretty much exactly what I am looking for. No need to complain about me asking a question though, considering what this site is for. Thanks!